# Combining chunks of pyaudio data into a single longer chunk

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, audio, microphone, pyaudio

I have a pyaudio stream running like so:

```
self.stream = self.microphone.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=self.SAMPLING_RATE, input=True, output=True, frames_per_buffer=self.SAMPLES_PER_CHUNK)
```

and I am saving each chunk to an array after decoding it through numpy like so:

```
data = self.stream.read(self.SAMPLES_PER_CHUNK)
data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='b')
recorded.append(list(data))
```

And I would later on like to be able to combine these chunks into a single array and save them to a wav file like this:

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

total = []
for i in recorded[start:stop]:
     total += i # the issue is here

write('output2.wav', 48000, np.array(total).astype('int16'))
```

But clearly it is not as simple as merging the arrays as the output file is always just a snippet of static. Could someone tell me how I should be doing this?

Comment: You should use `dtype='<i2'`, see https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-wave.ipynb for an example. If you want to avoid the hassle, you could also use modules that already support NumPy, like e.g. [sounddevice](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) and [soundfile](https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/). An example for recording chunks into a file: [rec_unlimited.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/rec_unlimited.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually realized that it was a question of decoding the data which means that if you change this:

data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='b')

To this:

data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='int16')

The rest of the code works just fine